# Search Box Customization in MOSS 2007

Tags: search, out-of-the-box

How to customize Search Box webpart so that to have a dropdown with items taken from a SharePoint list. User can search only from these dropdowns.

I know about configuiring scope. But this is little more.. I am looking for dropdown in 2nd box( Query box).

For ex: I have a list in my sharePoint site as Keywords. Now I want to add a Search Box in my home page where user can search which list they want to choose( can be done by search scope) and then input words in second search box. These words should come in a dropdown form with all contents from KeyWords library.

Hope I am clear with my explaination.

Answer (score 1):

you can add drop-down control on page after the free textbox using jquery. And while adding the drop-downto page also populate it with the data from the litusing jquery / list service. I have done similar thing in sharepoint 2010 .

Comment: can i get the jquery
??

Answer (score 0):

you could develop a custom delegate control.
In this post you can understand how: http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/delegate-controls-small-search-input.html

Comment: I need a drop down on Query text box on a Search Box webpart. that drop down should contain elements from another SharePoint list. the above link is somethin else..

Comment: The example of above explain you how you can create a delegate control from that you have to write your custom code.

Comment: Can't I just get a readymade code for dropdown:P...

Comment: @ankit : its long code ... provide you mail address i will send it to you